# Use Hashmap to check if a string is present

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap, key

Sorry for the newbie question, but I've never used Hashmaps before so I was a bit confused

I was trying to do something like this based on a post i saw here

I don't exactly get value means (is the default type for value an int?), so I wasn't sure what to do? I'm fine with just keeping a 0 or 1 value or a boolean or something. Can I just set value3=True or value3=1?
And if I use map.get is that getting the value? (presumably)
So if I used 0/1 I would want to check if (value3!=1)?
Thanks!

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
Object value3 = map.get("something_${blablabla}");

    if (value3 == null) {

        value3 = createValue("something_${row[blablabla]}");
        map.put("something_${row[blablabla]}", value3);
```

Comment: You want a hash **set**.

Comment: so i should use contains and add?

Comment: Set has add() method which returns true or false. See my answer below.

Comment: Be careful about adding Groovy Templated Strings to Sets/Maps.  See the [red box on this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store any meaningful value against your key then you should use HashMap. But, if you just want to store the unique keys and are not concerned about the values then you should go for HashSet. It will store the unique keys. And its add() method will return true or false depending on whether the value already exists or not.

Comment: i see, so something like..
HashSet itemset = new HashSet();
boolean present = itemset.add("something_${blablabla}");
    if (present == false) {   (the item was not present)
      do blank blank

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Think a Map as a dictionary: you have a word (key) and a description/translation (value). So if you are looking for a cenrtain value, you just do map.get(key) and obtains a value.

But if you just want to know if a key exists, but the value is not important, you should use a Set, not a Map